# How can i check if TextView is not empty in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I am building my first App. My question is:

How can i put the Intent into "liste2" when "liste1" is not empty?

**My Code:**

```
 private fun insertTextToTv() {
        val liste = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.liste)
        val liste2 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.liste2)
        val liste3 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.liste3)

        if (liste.text.toString() == "") {
            liste.text = intent.getStringExtra("key")
        } else {
            liste2.text = intent.getStringExtra("key")
        }

    }
}
```

**The Intent of the other Activity:**

```
 private fun favoritesButtonSaveText(){
        favorisieren.setOnClickListener{
            val save = Intent(this, favorites::class.java)
            save.putExtra("key", sourceTextField.text.toString())
            startActivity(save)
        }


    }
```

Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/is-empty.html

Comment: *put the Intent into "liste2"* What does this mean?

Comment: liste.text.toString().trim().equals("")

Comment: If you want to check if the textview has a value or null to decide your logic then you can use:

if(!liste.text.toString.matches(""))
{
    // textviews is not null not empty
     liste.text = getIntent().getStringExtra("key")
}else {
    //textview is null or empty
     liste2.text = getIntent().getStringExtra("key")
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private fun insertTextToTv() {
        val liste = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.liste)
        val liste2 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.liste2)
        val liste3 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.liste3)

        if (liste.text.isNotEmpty()) {
            liste2.text = intent.getStringExtra("key")
        } 

    }
```

}